# Change location of abstract in .sty file

Tags: packages, environments, titles, abstract

I am making a cover sheet for my university, which requires the very first page to contain some information and then from the second page, the document should follow the standard documentclass structure which has been chosen (in this case **article**).

My approach was to create a .sty file and redefine the `\maketitle`command and renew the abstract environment. Unfortunately, I keep failing at positioning the abstract underneath the title, author, etc. (as in the original article class). I am fairly certain that my `\renewenvironment{abstract}` is not correct. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

MWE:

**iccover.sty**

```
%% Start of `iccover.sty`
\ProvidesPackage{iccover}[2017/10/28 Custom Cover Page]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[textwidth=20cm, textheight=27.5cm]{geometry}

%% Redefining \maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
   \textbf{CUSTOM FIRST PAGE, NOTHING ELSE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE.}
   \null\vfil
   \newgeometry{textwidth=17cm,textheight=24cm}
\begin{titlepage}   
%% This is the standard title page of article.cls
   \let\footnotesize\small
   \let\footnoterule\relax
   \let \footnote \thanks
   \null\vfil
   \vskip 60\p@
   \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
        \lineskip .75em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
            \@author
        \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
   \end{center}\par
\end{titlepage}%

\setcounter{footnote}{0}
}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \begin{center}
        \bfseries \abstractname
    \end{center}}
%{\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}

%% End of `iccover.sty`
```

**sample.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{iccover}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Author}
\title{Some title}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're after.

You can define the `\abstract{<abstract>}` using a macro which is then set via `\maketitle` immediately after the regular title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{iccover.sty}
%% Start of `iccover.sty`
\ProvidesPackage{iccover}[2017/10/28 Custom Cover Page]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[textwidth=20cm, textheight=27.5cm]{geometry}

%% Redefining \maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \textbf{CUSTOM FIRST PAGE, NOTHING ELSE SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE.}

  \newgeometry{textwidth=17cm,textheight=24cm}
  \begin{titlepage}   
  %% This is the standard title page of article.cls
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}%
      {\LARGE \@title \par}%
      \vskip 3em%
      {\large
        \lineskip .75em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
          \@author
        \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
      {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
    \end{center}\par
    \csname @abstract\endcsname
  \end{titlepage}%

  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
}

\def\@abstract{}

\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{%
  \long\def\@abstract{%
    \begin{center}
        \bfseries \abstractname
    \end{center}
    #1\par
    \vspace{\bigskipamount}
  }%
}

%% End of `iccover.sty`
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{iccover}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Author}
\title{Some title}
\date{\today}
\abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting and simple approach, thank you! I wanted to ask, if you are aware of any differences between the `\abstract` macro and the `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` environment?